# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR - Extract value between string based on column value, and symbol

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

I have the following columns, I would like to search `Column 1` with the value from `Column 2`, and extract the between `Column2 || '/'` and the Comma afterwards.

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 040 |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 050 |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 060 |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 070 |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 080 |

Output

| Column1 | Column2 | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 040 | 1 |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 050 | 1 |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 060 | 2 |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 070 | 1 |
| Test Pack: 040/1,050/1,060/2,070/1,080/1 | 080 | 1 |

I have tried to use Regexp_substr but not sure how to use Column 2 in the Pattern parameter.
I think I should be able to do this with a complicated series of Substr + Instr, but wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: It it always a single character after `/`?

Comment: It may not be, ideally I would want to pull the value between COLUMN2 || '/' and the comma afterwards

Comment: The regexp would be `Column2 || '/' || '[^,]+'`

Comment: Use a capture group around `[^,]+` so you can extract just the number.

Comment: Almost there, looks like it extracts '040/1', how do I just pull the value after the forward slash?

Comment: See my last comment about using the capture group.

Comment: Apologies, still learning, what is a capture group?

Comment: Putting parentheses around part of a regexp so you can later refer to the part of the input that matched it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a regexp tutorial. Check out regular-expression.info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expression `regexp_substr(column1, column2||'/([^,]*)', 1, 1, null, 1)`.

Regex like `060/([^,]*)` will match literal string `060/` and everything what follows it, until first comma (if appears). Part after `/` will be captured into group number 1.

By default `regexp_substr` extracts full match, but with provided parameters, it extracts only content captured into group with number 1 (specifically last parameter does this). Details on parameters of `regexp_substr` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099).

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/m3DrSG3Q).

Demo of regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/5Poopl/1).

Comment: Works except for the last record (column 2 = 080), assuming since there is no comma afterwards?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for this, will help me understand how regex works with a practical example :)

Comment: @user15732949, I've provided some explanation to the answer. Also, regex101 provides decent explanation and in general great tool for regex debugging/experiments.

Comment: Regex101 is not always good for regular expressions in Oracle as they do not support the same syntax. There are many questions on StackOverflow where people state "it works on regex101" and expect it to also work in Oracle and quite often the answer is that you can't use the same regular expressions and you have to find an alternate method.